# awk remove all characters before match "/"

Tags: bash, shell

sorry for my bad english not my first language.
I have a text file with the following content, which is constantly changing in the column "directory":

```
DIRECTORY                          FILES      SIZE
documents/my_name/directory1/       2          96M
documents/my_name/directory2/       4          21M
documents/my_name//directory3/      1          43M
```

What I want is to remove the absolute path and leave only the name of the last directory.

Note: The third directory is written correctly, some addresses are written with two backslashes.

The result would be like this:

```
DIRECTORY       FILES       SIZE
directory1/       2          96M
directory2/       4          21M
directory3/       1          43M
```

or this:

```
DIRECTORY       FILES       SIZE
directory1       2          96M
directory2       4          21M
directory3       1          43M
```

Is there a way to do it using awk linux command or some other command?

Remember that the paths can be of different lengths, it is a file that always changes.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3):

check this out :

```
perl -pe 's:.*/([^/]+)/:\1:;s:/::g' file | column -t
```

or

```
perl -F"/" -lane 'print $F[-2], $F[-1] if @F >= 2 or $. == 1' file | column -t
```

or

```
perl -lane 'if ($.==1){print}else{($d,$f,$s)=@F;$d=~s/.*\/(.+?)\/$/$1/;print"$d\t$f\t$s"}' file | column -t
```

output:

```
DIRECTORY   FILES  SIZE
directory1  2      96M
directory2  4      21M
directory3  1      43M
```

Comment: Again, this is a file text file that always changes, It can have different path routes not only "documents/my_name/".

Comment: I think I explained it well. I want the last directory no matter what path it has.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Dear @Paolo , please undelete your answer and repost it with a little change. We miss you bro! 

Comment: @Freeman My answer was incorrect my friend.

Comment: @Paolo Well, fix it and put it back again. It's very easy for you considering the abilities I know you have!

Comment: @Freeman too kind. see you at the next question ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `match` function of `awk` with regex in it.

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{
  $1=$1
  print
  next
}
match($0,/\/[^/]+\/[[:space:]]+.*$/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: nice pattern thnx 1++

Comment: *Remember that the paths can be of different lengths* , this won't work

Comment: @Paolo, Thanks for pointing out, I have edited it now. Hope it takes care of that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print; next}
{split($1,a,"/"); $1=a[length(a)-1]} 1' file  | column -t
```

Prints:

```
DIRECTORY   FILES  SIZE
directory1  2      96M
directory2  4      21M
directory3  1      43M
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
rev file | cut -d/ -f 1,2 | rev
```

You can also use

```
sed -r 's#.*/(.*)/#\1/#' file
```

Comment: nice, thank you Walter 1++ 

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem using the awk command and the following options:

```
awk -F "/" '{print $(NF-1), $NF}' file.txt
```

I don't know if that's syntactically correct but it works for me.
Will it be reliable to solve it like this?

Comment: I got this error `awk: (FILENAME=file FNR=5) fatal: attempt to access field -1` to fix this better to write like this : `awk -F "/" 'NF >= 2 {print $(NF-1), $NF}' file`

Comment: Caused by the header line not containing any `/`. You need to prefix the script with an `NR==1 {print;next}` to just print and skip that. EDIT: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258457/667820 by @dawg

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that there are no blanks in the path

```
$ cat file
DIRECTORY                          FILES      SIZE
documents/my_name/directory1        2          96M
documents/my_name/directory2/       4          21M
documents/my_name//directory3/      1          43M
documents/my_name//directory4       1          43M
documents/my_name/directory5//      1          43M
documents/my_name//directory6//     1          43M

$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{sub(/\/*$/,"",$1); n=split($1,a,"/"); $1=a[n]}1' file
DIRECTORY       FILES   SIZE
directory1      2       96M
directory2      4       21M
directory3      1       43M
directory4      1       43M
directory5      1       43M
directory6      1       43M
```

Comment: good job,keep going! ++ 